# Exception Class Visibility?

Tags: c#, exception

Been using C# for about five years and only now did it strike me about the class visibility of custom exceptions. It's perfectly legal to write internal or even private nested exceptions like so:

```
internal class WhyDoThis : Exception { }

public class Foo { private class WhyWhyWhy : Exception { } }
```

So when you go about throwing these exceptions in your DLLs, only the (minority of) people doing decent (non pokemon) exception handling get their apps crashed.

So my question is, what's the purpose of such a  pattern? Or why is this even legal?

Comment: I think, probably, the later. It just a case that the compiler doesn't go that deep into analyzing the usage of a class. There isn't a mechanism to say, this class and anything derived from it must be public.

Comment: "Since "hidden" types would get exposed externally?" In what way? In that you'll be able to see *instances* of those exceptions? There's nothing new about that... `public class Foo { private class Bar{} public Object GiveMeABar() { return new Bar(); } }`

Comment: @JonSkeet aarrggh. Yes. That's pretty obvious now that you show it. Should have thought of that. Just got stuck on the utility.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does pokemon exception handling looks like? :)

Comment: @Crono try {...} catch(Exception e) {//gotta catch em all}   http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplistic answer would be: it's just as legal as any bad code can be.

I really can't think of anything else to say here that won't go beyond the scope of that question. That's just how it is. Anyone, at any time, can write code that even though can compile is just plain and simply awful.

**EDIT:**

I actually can think of *one* scenario where internal exceptions can have some use: for testing and asserting frameworks, like [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/). **But that's a very marginal case.**

Comment: It answers why it's legal. There are lots of bad code practices that are legal.

Comment: @DLeh Now the answer seems valid to me, at the time my comment was written it wasn't.

Comment: @ken2k is right. By the time I first answered I've read the question too fast and thought the issue was more about using exceptions to control flow than how their visibility is set. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

One purpose would be for an exception that is used internally to an assembly (or even privately to a class), but where the exception never escapes the assembly (or the class).  In that case, you wouldn't want it to become visible outside the assembly (or class).

In this case, it would obviously be a bug if the exception were to escape the assembly (or class).

Comment: That's still bad IMHO. If you create exceptions that can only be handled internally then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Agree with @Crono, you're using exceptions for the normal code flow in that case.

Comment: @ken2k, so you're saying that within a sub-system (internal to an assembly) you should not throw exceptions ever (that you intend to handle within that subsystem)--go back to using return values for errors?

Comment: catching exceptions only generated by that assembly, IMO, says nothing about whether it is the normal code flow or not.  Those are separate.

Comment: @MattSmith exceptions are for situations out of the programmer's control, like a critical file missing or a broken connection. You can also throw ArgumentException (and derived) for public APIs so that the app fails early on invalid parameters. Other than that, throwing exceptions that can only be catched internally is a bad idea. I can't think of a good reason why anyone would want to do that.

Comment: @MattSmith Not what I'm saying: I see the point of an internal exception, I don't see a valid reason to use a private nested exception class as the OP used.

Comment: @ken2k, ah gotchya--OP used both. It is definately hard to come up with a valid use case for the nested exception.

Comment: @Crono, "catching exceptions that can only be catched internally is a bad idea".  Why?  The boundary of an assembly can be pretty arbitrary.    Are you suggesting that for all code that is within your control you shouldn't throw exceptions that other parts of your code that are in your control catch?

Comment: @MattSmith You're right, OP used both, I focused on the second example while you focused on the first one :)

Comment: @MattSmith remember that we're talking about *custom* exceptions here. Since these exceptions are yours, then you know in which conditions they're thrown. And since obviously you know how to check on these conditions, then there's absolutely no reason for you to make a *try/catch*; instead check conditions *before* taking any actions.

Comment: @Crono, There are situations where that would violate separation of concerns.  If a given class shouldn't know about those conditions, it should throw and let the class that does know about those conditions catch and handle the error.  Imagine for example you put your *entire* program in one assembly--would you still recommend never throwing any custom exceptions?

Comment: How can a class not know about those conditions and yet know about the exception these conditions can end up throwing? IMHO concerns aren't properly separated there either, don't you think?

Comment: Also if the whole app holds into one assembly then what's the point of having custom exceptions?

Comment: Looks like everyone is assuming that ALL exceptions should absolutely be caught. Sometimes an exception is not meant to be caught, rather is meant to signal a defect. In this case, DON'T catch the exception, but rather, fix the defect!

Answer (score 1):

There nothing wrong from inheritance/visibility point of view to have internal/private exceptions. It is exactly the same as providing private class to implement public interface - whoever uses that object outside will not be able (short of reflection) to obtain details that are not exposed via public interface/base class.

So in exception case external callers will only be able to catch public base exception even if you fire very specific private exception. You may do that to provide custom `ToString` for example.

Note that private/internal exceptions are probably bad idea as whole reason of throwing specific exception is to let someone to catch specific one.

Also check out [Designing Custom Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229064%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to make sure your exception classes are useful in all cases (like cross-domain exceptions require serialization).